# What do you call a matrix where lower triangle is the negative of the upper triangle?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think there is a term for this, but I've been searching and I can't find out what it is.

$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
 a & b & c \\
-b & d & e \\
-c &-e & f \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are thinking of a skew-symmetric matrix, but this requires the diagonal to be 0 as well. It is skew-Hermitian if you require the diagonal to be imaginary and all other entries to be real. If the diagonal must have real values, then I don't believe there is an appropriate term for this, but you can call it the sum of a skew-symmetric and a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of skew-symmetric. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would call it the sum of a skew-symmetric and a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's called Skew Hermitian matrix.

Here is the Wikipedia  link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix)

Comment: Skew-hermitian seems to imply the diagonals are purely imaginary, with no real components.